# How to change the default value of color input in Google Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am building an extension and in my settings.html file I have a color input:

```
<input id="input_color" style="width: 20px; margin-left: 8px; margin-top: 3px;" type="color" value="#ff0000"><span class="radio"> Highlight color</span>
```

I thought that setting up the `value=""` will make the default color red, but If I install the extension, the color is set to black. I haven't find a solution of changing the color so It would be red after the installation of the extension.

What is the correct way of implementing this?

Comment: It correctly shows a red rectangle here. Not sure I understand the problem.

Comment: the problem is that It doesn't show the red rectangle... after I install the extension and open the settings.html, the rectangle is black @wOxxOm

Comment: Try to isolate the problem by commenting out various parts of your settings page html and code because the posted code alone correctly shows the red color.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding it to the `style` property instead

```
<input id="input_color"
  style="width: 20px; margin-left: 8px; margin-top: 3px; color: #ff0000">
```

Comment: still nothing, after instalation of the extension, if I open the extension, the colorpicker is still black @molamk